# What is the difference between "Entrometido" and "Entremetido"?

Tags: definiciones, sinónimos

The definition of entrometido in the rae just sends you to entremetido.

Is there a real difference between the two? And if there isn't then why are there two words with exactly the same meaning. Maybe something to do with its origin?

Comment: `Metiche` is also very common

Comment: One is surely a deformation of the other. I only know/use "entrometido", "entremetido" sounds wrong to me.

Comment: `metiche` is the most common in the spoken language. `Entrometido` is a more formal synonym as well as `entremetido`, but `entremetido` is hardly used at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas has this to say regarding `Entremetido` and `Entrometido`

> entremeter(se). ‘Meter [una cosa] en medio de otra o poner(se) una
>   persona o cosa entre otras’: «Se abalanzó hacia la enciclopedia,
>   eligió el tomo octavo, [...] entremetió en él la foto» (Cohen Muerte
>   [Esp. 1993]); «Otros se entremetieron entre los muertos, se fingieron
>   muertos para escapar» (Solares Nen [Méx. 1994]); y, como pronominal,
>   ‘intervenir alguien en un asunto que no le incumbe’: «No quieren que
>   nadie se entremeta en su vida» (Rausch Dietas [Arg. 1996]). Con este
>   último sentido **es hoy mayoritario el uso de entrometer(se)**: «Tuvo
>   cuidado de no entrometerse demasiado en los problemas políticos»
>   (Serrano Dios [Col. 2000]). Lo mismo cabe decir de los adjetivos
>   derivados entremetido y entrometido, mucho más frecuente este último:
>   «No tocó la ropa de Gustavo, [...] porque no quería que la acusara de
>   entrometida» (Donoso Elefantes [Chile 1995]); «No faltaban
>   transeúntes, curiosos, entremetidos y preguntones» (Otero Temporada
>   [Cuba 1983]).

To put it more clearly: the meaning is the same but when you are using it as synonym for `metido/metiche` the word should be `Entrometido`; otherwise, `Entremeter`:

> Eres muy entrometido ¿Por qué mejor no te ocupas de tu vida?
>
> Entremetí el dinero en el libro que llevaba en mi mano

Answer (score 3):

From RAE:

> [**Entremetido**](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltObtenerHtml?IDLEMA=75741&NEDIC=Si)
>
> (Del part. de entremeter).
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que tiene costumbre de meterse donde no la llaman. U. t. c. s.
>
> [**Entrometido**](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltObtenerHtml?IDLEMA=75747&NEDIC=Si)
>
> 1. adj. **entremetido**. U. t. c. s.

So they are synonyms and it means a person who intrudes into other people's affairs (meddler or meddling person). At least in Spain **entrometido** is the one used for this meaning. I have never heard "**entremetido**" (though people would guess the meaning).

As you can see with [**Ngram Viewer**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entremetido,%20entrometido&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=10&smoothing=3) now **entrometido** is more common though **entremetido** was common in the past.

[image]

Also entremetido can be used as a participle of the verb **[entremeter](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltObtenerHtml?IDLEMA=31245&NEDIC=Si)**. In that case it can mean to place something between other things. But I'd say that "meter entre" is more common than "entremeter" (at least in Spain).

Answer (score 0):

Correct word: entremetido.

Corrupt use: entrometido.

Sentence: Es un entrometido. Se mete en todas las salsas. Un perfecto salsero (listillo o métome en todo).

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuetas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!